# Why does Visual Studio run in "Always on top" mode?

Tags: visual-studio, always-on-top

My copy of Visual Studio seems to be set in "Always On Top" Mode. It runs this way by default; there seems to be no way of changing it.

Visual Studio runs as Administrator/Elevated, but that really shouldn't affect whether or not Visual Studio runs as "Always On Top."

Any idea why this may be occurring, and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: I saw a glimpse of this problem with Visual Studio 2010 starting to run "Always On Top" in Windows7, but it only happened straight upon a ReSharper update, and got resolved as soon as Visual Studio was restarted.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you refer to?

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed also? It seems to have a history of causing this type of issue on various versions.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27411034/2667554

Comment: Simple restart of visual studio 2010 helped me also.

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar thing happen with Visual Studio being stuck as always on top. It started happening after I hit the Windows key followed by a bunch of arrow/home/end/pageup/pagedn keystrokes by accident (I had meant to use the control key).

What seemed to clear the always-on-top behavior was to select a different application (eg: Chrome), then press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> (which minimized everything other than Chrome), then press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> again. Then I could un-minimize Visual Studio, and it would no longer be always on top.

This worked with VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013 when they got into this weird always on top mode.

Edit: revised based on comment from @Nebula

Comment: This work around didn't work for me.
Windows-Alt-Home seems to just tell Chrome to go to the home page. Focusing on the desktop and Windows-Alt-Home didn't seem to work either.

- I run VS2010 in Admin mode
- Resharper
- Windows 7

I don't have a solution, just giving feedback

Comment: This almost worked for me; I had to press Windows+Home (I didn't know about that one) and then simply pressed Windows+Home again. Windows+Alt+Home just sent my chrome to it's homepage. So: Windows+Home -> wait for the windows to come down -> Windows+Home -> Fixed!

Comment: As @Nebula pointed out, the ALT modifier should not be used. Confirmed fix for VS 2017 as well! :)

Comment: Works perfectly with vs2017

Comment: Thanks! This works with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: That has to be the strangest fix ever... but it worked on VS 2019, thank you!

Comment: Windows+Home does nothing for me, I suspect because I have disabled the "shake a window to minimize other programs" feature.

Comment: works with Visual studio 2022

Comment: Still works in VS 2023

Answer (score 7):

Save your work, close Visual Studio, reopen it. Hit start, or debug, or hit F5.

This worked for me.

Very strange though, for months I didn't have this problem, and earlier when I started debugging, my window was behind Visual Studio's window... Thought it strange as it never happened before. Closed Visual Studio, reopened it, and viola.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue with VS2017 on Windows 10 by giving focus to another application and pressing Windows+Home (to minimize all windows apart from the one which got focus) and then Windows+Home again to restore all other windows (including VS) and this time VS wasn't always on top anymore.

Comment: +1 This worked for me with Visual Studio 2019. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to get it out of that mode by using Window->Float to undock a tab. After I dragged the tab back onto the main window, it was no longer stuck on top.

Comment: I even didn't need to have the step of 'undocking' a tab; I just dragged it out then put it back onto the main window, and now it is good! it happened as I restarted using ReSharper 2019

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this with Visual Studio 2019 (on Windows 10).  I'm not sure quite how it started, but I do use ReSharper.  Closing and restarting VS2019 did not work.  I also installed a minor update (probably before restarting VS; I'm not sure if this might have actually locked-in the always-on-top behavior or made no difference--probably the latter, but I mention it just in case).  I tried the various solutions here and in other linked pages and none seemed to help (I might not have hit all of them; some were more involved or meant for older versions or otherwise hard to try).

Finally, on a whim, I tried launching a second instance of VS 2019--since they can't both be on top at the same time--and after minimizing the first instance to get to the second, I found that the new instance did not force itself on top of other windows.  I closed out the first instance and then re-opened my solution in the new instance, and it no longer forces itself on top.  I just checked that it stays fixed after restarting VS 2019 also.

**Update:** This can help turn off the always-on-top state at a particular time, but it doesn't prevent it from potentially happening again.  I'm not sure what causes it, but VS does get back into being always-on-top from time to time when a new VS instance is started.  So, it's a temporary but not permanent fix.

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an addin is causing it? Try disabling addins in Tools/Add-in manager then run Visual Studio in safe mode by executing

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

Comment: this is the definitive answer imho.

Comment: works like a charm with after installing Resharper 8.2 !

Answer (score 2):

Use [windowdetective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/) to check if it's actually set to always ontop
Work from there to determine the cause.

Answer (score 1):

The "good ol' close & reopen" method will resolve this issue silently. Just save your work, close Visual Studio and reopen your project/solution and this unintended setting will go away. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some reason, the always-on-top property of your Visual Studio (VS) is being saved somewhere and then reloaded on run.
Depending on your VS version, you may be able to use [FileBox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/downloads.asp)(FBX) to change its always-on-top property for each run or permanently. It is probably better to use the version matching your Windows' architecture; 64-bit for x64 and 32-bit for x86. Also, FBX can probably be only used for elevated-mode programs if itself is run in elevated mode (e.g. "Run as Administrator").
Always-on-top status can be switched by clicking the pushpin on the program title bar when FileBox eXtender is running.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this problem I found a solution to the reverse problem over at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/196958/the-3-best-ways-to-make-a-window-always-on-top-on-windows). Luckily it involved a TOGGLE which I could use to disable the always on top mode that Visual Studio's window had gotten into. As per the above link, I added this to my AutoHotkey script

> ^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A

and then I selected Visual Studio's window and used ctrl-space to toggle always on top. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio 2015 fixed the problem.

In my case, VS switched in "Always On Top" mode while I was using intellisense from ReSharper.